# Why default value of an optional parameter must be a constant?

Tags: dart

```
class Foo {
  final DateTime date;
  static final DateTime defDate = DateTime.now();
  
  Foo([this.date = defDate]); // Error
}
```

What's wrong in this code, I am providing a `static` `final` value as the default value to the optional parameter, but it isn't acceptable by Dart, can anyone please explain this behavior?

---

Edit:

```
// Global field
final DateTime defDate = DateTime.now();

class A {
  void a([DateTime i = defDate]) => a; // Shouldn't have an error
}

class B extends A {
  @override
  void a([DateTime i = defDate]) => a; // Shouldn't have an error
}
```

Comment: A search on the Dart language GitHub issue tracker found the following issues with some discussion: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/140 and https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart default values must be compile-time constant for a number of reasons.

First of all, the default value is considered part of the signature of instance methods.
Subclasses must override a method with parameters taking the same default value. That is meaningless if the value isn't known at compile-time.

More importantly is that there is not a single obvious time when the expression should be evaluated. Dart deliberately avoids evaluating anything before starting `main` to  reduce startup latency. The only exception is compile-time constants because they can be evaluated entirely at compile-time.
That means that when you all a function with a default value the first time, the default value would not have been evaluated yet. It would definitely need to be evaluated at that point, at least if you omit an argument for the parameter, so the compiler might have to evaluate an arbitrary expression in the middle of a function call. Apart from the extra overhead, which is a problem by itself, the real issue is that it makes the code unpredictable.
In your example, the default value would be the `DateTime.now()` that happened to be the time when the function was first called.

The alternative would be evaluating the default value expression every time the function is called without an argument for that parameter. The Dart language team are considering that option (as a *potential* future move, no real current plans), but it would mean dropping the idea that the default value is a part of the signature.
Until the language does such a thing, the default value must be constant.

Comment: AFAIK, there shouldn't be a problem when overriding methods when you are providing them a static field or a global final field (please see my edited post).
Second, the static fields are only created once an object of a class is instantiated,
so I don't think that it will be an overhead to do just a one time work.
Maybe I don't posses enough information to understand this much of theory without code. I'd appreciate your efforts and you surely deserve an upvote.

Comment: Static and top-level variables in Dart are lazily initialized, so they are only evaluated the first time they are read. Static fields are not linked to object instantiation, they are equivalent to top-level variables except that you need to write `ClassName.` in front of them, but that's just a namespace. Using those as default values would link the initialization to the call of the method which uses them as default value, which is an overhead on the call and would make initialization implicit and unpredictable. The only way to have truly evaluation order independent code is const.

Comment: Thanks sir, this made sense now.